# SpringBoot src [main] issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

Does anyone know why this would be happening? Other projects I have show src -> main as bolded.

[[image: src main]g

I have tried unmarked directories and recreating the source directory as java as I was having a separate issue.

Answer (score 0):

I mistakenly set src as the main in my gradle and its now fixed.

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ["main"]
        }
    }
}
```